# Representing equation in set theory notation

Tags: combinatorics, notation

I have a metric `coverage` which for a given set is defined as the ratio of number of items in the given set that are also in the union of all the sets over the number of items in the union, with an added constraint that the union comprises of those items that exist in at least two sets.

For example, let $A = \{1,2,3\}$, $B = \{2,3,4\}$ and $C = \{4,5\}$. Then $U = \{2,3,4\}$ and

$$\operatorname{coverage}(A) = \frac{|\{2,3\}| }{ |\{2,3,4\}| } = 0.66,$$

and

$$\operatorname{coverage}(C) = \frac{|\{4\}| }{ |\{2,3,4\}| }= 0.33.$$

How can I represent the equation of `coverage` using set theory notations?

Comment: As a nitpick, equals signs should only be used for equality and $\frac{2}{3}$ is not equal to $0.66$.  On to your question, this is not a standard operation and so does not have its own name or symbol, but you can define it easily enough.  Letting the sets be labeled with subscripts as $A_1,A_2,\dots,A_k$ you can define $U$ as $U=\{x~:~\exists i,j,~~i\neq j,~x\in A_i\cap A_j\}$ and your "coverage" would then be $\text{coverage}_{A_i} = \dfrac{|A_i\cap U|}{|U|}$

Comment: As long as we are nitpicking, I really don't get why people think writing numbers as decimals is somehow supposed to be more correct or better than writing them as fractions.  Decimals are *less* correct and writing as decimals is *worse* and less clear.  Better to  so coverage A = $\frac 23$ and coverage C = $\frac 13$.  That actually means *more* and gives us *more* useful information than the, actually incorrect and wrong, coverage A = $0.66$ and coverage_B = $0.33$.  Rant off.

Comment: @fleablood: Decimals is pretty nifty if you need to compare values. For example, I couldn't tell you whether $\frac{41}{64}$ is more or less than $\frac{207}{317}$ without calculating, but giving some decimal approximations instead of the fractions settles it immediately.

Comment: True.  But such quantitative measures are a lot less relevant in abstract math than a novice would think.  Nearly always knowing how a value is made and what it is composed of will be more important then what size it actually is.  In the case of *this* problem converting to decimals is ... pointless and will trip things up *horribly* for any more complicated procedures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let K be a collection of sets.
Define the weak union of K as
{ x : exists distinct A,B in K with x in A $\cap$ B }.

For A in K, the coverage of A is |A|/|weak union K|.